# Visual Studio 2012 Add Reference Browse Default Path

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Most of my solutions will have an *External References* folder inside the same folder as my Visual Studio solution. Usually solutions will have a few of the same DLLs, but it is important for each solution to have its own copy for the build machine and in case of different version numbers.

Previously in Visual Studio 2010 and earlier, when I add a reference to a DLL *External References* folder the file browser dialog will open in the last folder that I added a reference to for this specific Visual Studio solution (or maybe project). In Visual Studio 2012 (Update 3) it seems to open the file browser in the last folder that I referenced, regardless of if it was within the current Visual Studio Solution or not. This means that I sometimes reference a DLL in a another solution's *External References* folder by mistake.

How can I change this back to the Visual Studio 2010 behaviour?

Comment: Completely not answering your question, but why not just use nuget? it handles the library code scenario really well

Comment: I do for public DLLs. For various reasons I cannot maintain a private nuget repository.